# Windows 10 disk load 100% caused by ekrn.exe

Tags: windows-10, performance

Recently I updated my PC from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and everytime I turn it on for 20-30 minutes is extremly slow. Task Manager shows disk at 100%. I checked why and I found out that is caused by `ekrn.exe` and other process but this one looks the main reason that slows my PC. 
I'll show you some of these processes (there are many more). I've cleened registers with Ccleaner. This never happend with Windows 7.
Can you help me?

```
Processo    PID File    Lettura (B/sec) Scrittura (B/sec)   Totale (B/sec)  Priorità I/O    Tempo di risposta (ms)
ekrn.exe    140 C:\$Mft (Tabella file master NTFS)  475.750 0   475.750 Normale 6
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys 318.874 0   318.874 Normale 5
svchost.exe 2004    C:\Windows\System32\UserDataService.dll 19.456  0   19.456  Normale 23
System  4   C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f674c3a77cfe39d0.automaticDestinations-ms  14.809  0   14.809  Normale 28
RuntimeBroker.exe   5040    C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Storage.Search.dll  12.587  0   12.587  Normale 3
RuntimeBroker.exe   5040    C:\Windows\System32\SearchFolder.dll    11.349  0   11.349  Normale 20
svchost.exe (LocalServiceNoNetwork) 1212    C:\Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles\ShutdownCKCL.etl   10.842  0   10.842  Background  7.868
System  4   C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\de48a32edcbe79e4.automaticDestinations-ms  10.283  0   10.283  Normale 23
svchost.exe (LocalSystemNetworkRestricted)  404 C:\Windows\System32\Chakra.dll  9.397   0   9.397   Background  7.874
System  4   C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\89173367336f4ea0.automaticDestinations-ms  9.173   0   9.173   Normale 24
RuntimeBroker.exe   5040    C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Internal.Shell.Broker.dll   7.607   0   7.607   Normale 30
RuntimeBroker.exe   5040    C:\$Mft (Tabella file master NTFS)  6.617   0   6.617   Normale 27
System  4   C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\422397bcc2e274f5.automaticDestinations-ms  5.396   0   5.396   Normale 434
ekrn.exe    140 C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f674c3a77cfe39d0.automaticDestinations-ms  5.317   0   5.317   Normale 22
System  4   C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\84f066768a22cc4f.automaticDestinations-ms  4.805   0   4.805   Normale 23
RuntimeBroker.exe   5040    C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll 3.781   0   3.781   Normale 23
System  4   C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\46f433176bc0b3d2.automaticDestinations-ms  2.746   0   2.746   Normale 22
System  4   C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\e70d383b15687e37.automaticDestinations-ms  2.645   0   2.645   Normale 22
System  4   C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\adecfb853d77462a.automaticDestinations-ms  2.133   0   2.133   Normale 22
perfmon.exe 2044    C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll   1.928   0   1.928   Normale 52
ekrn.exe    140 C:\$Secure:$SDS 1.365   0   1.365   Normale 12
msfeedssync.exe 5776    C:\Windows\System32\netjoin.dll 1.312   0   1.312   Bassa   5.753
RuntimeBroker.exe   5040    C:\Windows\System32\actxprxy.dll    1.170   0   1.170   Normale 14
svchost.exe 2004    C:\$Mft (Tabella file master NTFS)  1.024   0   1.024   Normale 17
RuntimeBroker.exe   5040    C:\$Secure:$SDS 945 0   945 Normale 26
backgroundTaskHost.exe  3404    C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Cortana.ProxyStub.dll   878 0   878 Background  5.406
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6de9cb26d2b98c01ec4e9e8b34824aa2_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   853 0   853 Normale 8
System  4   C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\af812ab767785035.automaticDestinations-ms  838 0   838 Normale 33
ekrn.exe    140 C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\12dc1ea8e34b5a6.automaticDestinations-ms   811 0   811 Normale 21
ekrn.exe    140 C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\590aee7bdd69b59b.customDestinations-ms    745 0   745 Normale 24
ekrn.exe    140 C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\7e4dca80246863e3.automaticDestinations-ms  698 0   698 Normale 27
svchost.exe (LocalSystemNetworkRestricted)  404 C:\$Mft (Tabella file master NTFS)  683 0   683 Background  7.544
ekrn.exe    140 C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\ccc0fa1b9f86f7b3.customDestinations-ms    670 0   670 Normale 26
ekrn.exe    140 C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\9645f58513b1a821.customDestinations-ms    640 0   640 Normale 31
RuntimeBroker.exe   5040    C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations   585 0   585 Normale 33
ekrn.exe    140 C:\Users\Gabriele\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\ec3e36af0cdcb3e1.customDestinations-ms    551 0   551 Normale 22
hola_svc.exe    2060    C:\Program Files\Hola\app\hola_svc.exe  546 0   546 Normale 390
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6da924e94eb8ebd1d5c57479251a3e18_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 35
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6decd32ae07290b5c030d92bbb872c31_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 29
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6da085a4f38d1ffb871817758f7f0ed6_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 26
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d63cf2ef293947889e1567929f4e7d4_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 26
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d996901c4cd6c2e8c46fbadd18c4a41_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 24
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d7a382519d460d1b8f23fde95c324ba_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 21
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d8ae00c4c3f48b27e215d0448915cd0_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 15
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6da473513714caedaeb5bdc4797eaeae_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 13
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d695c73a61ad91854e1c195dfda40bd_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 13
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d732e13606013b0b9966f162efb7236_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 12
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6dd7f24472c13ff1a2ff397ccd046354_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 12
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d5c85b53cfa818060bca8572e721b21_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 12
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d74cdb7daca3222cb9cad75700f53c1_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 12
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d86b04661eeca3dba750a0d4e76a1d7_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 12
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d5caa9e09ae811ba6879988241ca9d7_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 12
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6deac45003973555f962a2c0a8f8c8ed_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 12
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d6c613c4440d344e2a73cb0b15c4e34_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d84327e381687bd7132be988b99996e_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6dfc319bb106c964160fd072e2bea794_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6dc51070c4f4fb8a893394871cb2b592_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d603b179cb3649ad0559b63798cce61_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d74dc0df4bd7aac1e758019c39b8d9a_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6da484e926c43c1d822171003b3bc02b_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6dd829601574228cd20c36bd9a8dc2be_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6dece52cb238de65f1ae969f2260c4b1_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d733b6b2329fedb1d81c84a7ab9ce8e_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d996b10fa785be242f24a178a7e25d2_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6da9401d5c2edaa662f59a4f3b48dcea_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d71bf1b902d38297dabf679cf0ad459_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d73ac20ac0927d45242ded205612eb8_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d65699f63bbf54a87eda7e762516e9b_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d63ed92bf68d3333fc37df00f7f34fd_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d64a52b6360b6f139e7450cbd20d1e8_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6da096f23ac8b49e909bff561a59782b_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6dd523a3a9cbf97c36434909497d9bc4_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 11
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6deb12571add4950ff016e700338c0c6_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 10
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d675bb4621cc032c86d249da60dee8d_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 10
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d873f06866e1168fed5ef3affaf0ca3_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 10
ekrn.exe    140 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\6d62b0d0382a013039ab7e255e8b8bd0_0400ac6f-2f18-4eb9-bea3-6cb0de023e61   512 0   512 Normale 10
```

Edit: screenshot for  magicandre1981. [Here's the link. I can't embed images until I reach 10 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgrUR.png)

Comment: open a cmd as admin, run this **"C:\Windows\System32\wpr.exe" -start DiskIO && timeout -1 "C:\Windows\System32\wpr.exe" -stop C:\HighDiskIO.etl** when you see the highdisk usage, after 30-60s press a key to stop logging. share the ETL (compressed as 7z/RAR to reduce file size) . I'll take a look at the trace.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Don't mind about the first error. With a space between `-` and `1` says: The profiles are already running. Profile Id: DiskIO.Verbose.Memory Error code: 0xc5583001

Comment: add a space and **&&** after the **-1**

Comment: I have bo high disk IO with NOD32. in the options configure the realtime scanning to only scan on write and read/execute, not normal read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft made some changes that conflict with certain versions of the product ([see here](http://support.eset.com/kb3747/?&page=content&id=SOLN3747)).
Try uninstalling & reinstalling the software to see if the helps. I've seen allot of different Anti-Virus programs behave strangely after OS upgrades.

Worst case scenario, you can always backup your data, and do a fresh install with your Windows 7 key.
http://www.howtogeek.com/224342/how-to-clean-install-windows-10/

Comment: When I reinstalled ESS the disk has become slow again. I think I need to find another antivirus. Or back to Windows 7. This thing really sucks...Do you know any good antivirus compatible with Windows 10?

Comment: I use BitDefender Free edition on my computers http://www.bitdefender.com/solutions/free.html

Answer (score 1):

This process usually belongs to ESET Antivirus. Use this uninstaller here: http://support.eset.com/kb146/?locale=en_US to uninstall everything ESET-related.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm using that antivirus. The fact is that never happend with Windows 7.